# Cookie issue on google chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, remember-me

I encounter a cookie issue with my website.

When a customer click on "remember me" before log-in, a cookie is created, and then when he leave and come back later, he is automatically re-logged.

It works on firefox/IE & co, but not for chrome...

I have wrote a little script to test the cookies creation on chrome. Here it is :

```
<?php 
if( isset($_GET['test']) ) setcookie('TESTSOMECOOKIE',1234,time()+60*60*24*365);
?>
```

It can't be more simple!

When I run the script :

1. The cookie is created properly.
2. If I close the tab and open a new one (without pass the test param), the cookie still exists.
3. If I close google chrome and re-open it, and go to the test script (without pass the test param), the cookie is not present anymore... and if I do that on firefox or IE no problem the cookie still present in all cases.
4. I'm  trying this on a webserver ( not a local IP address ).
5. I have NOT activated the private navigation on chrome.
6. Cookies are enabled and works like on gmail/facebook, etc... chrome keep the cookies for these sites!
7. I already checked other issues posted on the web but no real answers about that...

So, this is a very weird issue that I would like to solve if possible.

If anyone have an idea...

Thank you very much for your suggestions and sorry for my english

Comment: did you see if you have "Keep local data only until I quit my browser" checked in your chrome settings? its under Content Settings > Cookies

Comment: @David Chase : OMG I feel very very stupid... indeed you found the solution. Many thanks!

Comment: can you mark the answer correct below so others can use it as well

Comment: Seems it was already done by someone else? Sorry I'm new on stack. And I can't increase the votes my reputation does not allow it :(
Thanks

Comment: not increase votes but marked it accepted, add a check mark (it should be under the arrows when you hover) next to the answer so people dont add other answers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to see if `Keep local data only until I quit my browser` is checked.

Its located in `Settings > Content Settings > Cookies`.

See if that helps.